# É necessário repetir as dependências(JAR)?

Tags: java

Eu tenho um "projeto A" que usa uma biblioteca java .JAR , que está dentro das dependências.
Eu exportei esse projeto pra .JAR para usar no "projeto B" . Esse projeto B precisa usar também a mesma biblioteca.

Eu preciso usar nos dois ou em apenas um deles ?

Comment: Se ao criar o jar, você editou a build.xml para que importasse todas as dependencias necessárias do projeto A para dentro do seu jar, não precisa. Mas se você precisa levar o jar da biblioteca junto com o do projeto A para que ele funcione, então a resposta é sim, precisa dos dois.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, se o projeto B depende siretamente da biblioteca ela deve ser incluída no classpath tanto durante a compilação quanto durante a execução.

Algo que é necessário ser entendido em Java é que o fato de ter um suas classes compiladas em um JAR não significa que ele possui suas dependências embutidas. Existem algumas ferramentas que conseguem juntar as dependências dentro do JAR, mas não é a regra e nem recomendado na maioria dos casos.

Mesmo quando o projeto B não depende diretamente da biblioteca, mas faz uso indireto dela você ainda vai precisar incluí-la em tempo de execução (comando `java`), embora não seja necessário em tempo de compilação  (comando `javac`).

O que algumas vezes nos confunde é que ferramentas como Maven e Gradle trazem automaticamente as dependências de dependências em um determinado projeto, chamadas dependências transitivas. Isso ajuda quando não dependemos diretamente delas, mas não é incomum usarmos dependências transitavam diretamente, o que é um erro, já que essas dependências transitivas podem mudar se a dependência direta for atualizada de versão, p orçamento exemplo, além de que fica pouco intuitivo para manutenção do projeto.

O único caso em que você não precisa incluir a biblioteca no projeto B, seja em compilação ou execução, é quando você não faz uso direto nem indireto, isto é, você faz uso apenas de um subconjunto de classes do projeto A que, por sua vez, não faz uso direto da biblioteca.